# How to prevent the Qt-provided Zlib's deflateend(&compr_str) function from segfaulting when the application is built with mingw on windows?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, mingw, zlib

### Introduction

I use the below code for a Gzip compression in my code and experience the code segfaulting under very specific conditions. I am basically completely lost after trying to solve it myself.

The code is is built with the following configurations:

1. Linux x86-64 Ubuntu 18.04, Qt 5.12.7 built from source, using the system zlib.
2. Linux arm x86-64 Yocto, Qt 5.12.7 built from source, using the system zlib.
3. Windows MSVC2017 64 Bit, Qt 5.12.7 from the official installer, using a self built zlib because Qt does not ship one for MSVC
4. Windows MinGW-x86-64, Qt 5.12.7 from the official installer, using the shipped zlib

In configuration [1-3], the test call to the compression code succeeds.
In configuration [4], the test call to the compression code succeeds when started from within the Qt creator IDE.
In configuration [4], the test call to the compression code leads to a segfault as soon as calling `deflateEnd(&cmpr_stream);`, when built from a Power shell command line like so:
1. Setting the same environment variables in power shell like the Qt Creator ide uses as build environment.ACLineStatus
2. Calling the exact same commands like configured in the Qt Creator IDE for the MinGw-x86-64 config.

I can reproduce a similar crash at that specific line, even when the test is called *inside* qt creator, when I try to use a buffer size of 32768 for both MSVC and MinGw. MSVC crashes with 16384 and MinGw crashes with 32768, hence the `#ifdef` below in my code for the buffer size.

### Questions

- Does the actual compression code below look ok in general? It was not written by me initially and I did not learn yet in detail how to properly use zlib, however, a lot of example code throughout the web looks similar.
- What could potentially lead to a crash in ZLIB where their documentation states that "the lib should never crash, even in case of corrupted input"?
- What could be the cause for the segfault that happen when I build the application from the command line with mingw32 with the same build environment variables as inside of the qt creator ide, where the resultinh build does not crash on execution?

I did both mingw builds (qt creator build with calling the test form inside the IDE, as well as the manual cli build with calling the test from the command line) to test the behaviour on clean virtual machines with only QT installed and nothing else, to have absolute identical and clean environments before starting any of the builds.

### The code that segfaults

```
#define BASE2_ZLIB_WINDOWSIZE 15
#define GZIP_ZLIB_WINDOWSIZE (16 + BASE2_ZLIB_WINDOWSIZE)
#define MOD_GZIP_ZLIB_CFACTOR 9
#define MOD_GZIP_ZLIB_BSIZE 8096

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE 32768
#else
#define COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE 16384
#endif

QByteArray gzipCompress(QByteArray data, int compressionlevel)
{
    char buffer[COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE];

    z_stream cmpr_stream;
    cmpr_stream.next_in = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(data.data());
    cmpr_stream.avail_in = static_cast<uInt>(data.size());
    cmpr_stream.total_in = 0;
    cmpr_stream.total_out = 0;

    cmpr_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    cmpr_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;

    QByteArray compressed;

    // the actual compression work.
    if (deflateInit2(&cmpr_stream, compressionlevel, Z_DEFLATED, GZIP_ZLIB_WINDOWSIZE, MOD_GZIP_ZLIB_CFACTOR,
                        Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY) != Z_OK)
    {
        return compressed;
    }
    // retrieve the compressed bytes blockwise
    int ret;
    do
    {
        cmpr_stream.next_out = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(buffer);
        cmpr_stream.avail_out = COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE;
        ret = deflate(&cmpr_stream, Z_FINISH);

        if (static_cast<unsigned long>(compressed.size()) < cmpr_stream.total_out)
        {
            // append the block to the output string
            compressed.append(buffer, static_cast<int>(cmpr_stream.total_out) - compressed.size());
        }
    } while (ret == Z_OK);

    deflateEnd(&cmpr_stream);

    if (ret != Z_STREAM_END)
    {
        return QByteArray();
    }
    return compressed;
}
```

### The test, calling the code

```
TEST(Compression, gzipSuccessfull)
{
    QString string_data(
        "Complex Test 256/n Data complete Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr "
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr");
    QByteArray raw = string_data.toLatin1();
    qDebug() << "Orig size: " << raw.size();
    // Crashes in the next line
    QByteArray compressed = gzipCompress(raw);
    qDebug() << "Compressed size: " << compressed.size();
    QByteArray uncompressed = gzipDecompress(compressed);
    qDebug() << "Uncompressed size: " << uncompressed.size();
    QString restored = QString::fromLatin1(uncompressed);
    ASSERT_TRUE(string_data == restored);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is causing your segfault, but you need to initialize `zfree`. It looks like a copy/paste error in your code, since you initialize `zalloc` twice. Should be:

```
cmpr_stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
cmpr_stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
```

and to be complete:

```
cmpr_stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
```

Your computation of how much to append looks correct, but it is a roundabout way to do it, and could have a portability problem if `long` is 32 bits. In that case, `total_out` would not represent the total amount out when more than 4 GB. Instead you should directly use the result from `deflate()`:

```
    if (cmpr_stream.avail_out < COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        // append the block to the output string
        compressed.append(buffer, COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE - cmpr_stream.avail_out);
    }
```

Since the parameter to `append` is an `int` instead of `unsigned`, you should make sure that `COMPR_BUFFER_SIZE` fits in an `int`.

Comment: Indeed, you found and correctly identified the copy and paste mistake, not initializing zfree. The issue with having to define a bigger buffer for MSVC is gone as well after I added your suggestion.